# redirecting to default language directory if no language have been selected - .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

basically what i have in my .htaccess is couple of lines to detected the selected fake*sub-folder language and redirecting automatic to ?lang=(selected language)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /bb/

RewriteCond ^(fr|en|ar)/?(.*)?$ !-d
RewriteRule ^en/?(.*)?$ ./$1?lang=English [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^fr/?(.*)?$ ./$1?lang=French  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ar/?(.*)?$ ./$1?lang=Arabic  [L,QSA]
```

so any URL look like this one for example : `localhost/bb/fr/`

will header to `localhost/bb/index.php?lang=French` in background but keeping the requested fake*sub-folder in the same time exist in the url

and it works perfect but there is still something necessary to do which is :

**if no language is selected** and the user is on the url : `localhost/bb/` or `localhost/bb/index.php` it should redirect him by default to English **(`localhost/bb/en`)** since he didn't select any

what i tried is :

```
RewriteCond !^(fr|en|ar)/?(.*)?$ !-d
RewriteRule !^(fr|en|ar)/?(.*)?$ ./en/$1 [L,R]
```

but that causes a weird infinite loop that look like : 
`localhost/bb/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/?lang=English?lang=English?lang=English?lang=English?lang=English?lang=English`

same result if i do :

```
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:en|ar|fr)/)(.*)$ en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and if i use something like :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/((en|ar|fr)/.*)$
RewriteRule .* ./en/%1 [L,R=301]
```

which is suggested by other Q-answers in the community here

it fire an Error like : 
**`localhost redirected you too many times.`**

Any Suggestions or solutions with Examples will be appreciated a lot .

Comment: `RewriteCond ^(fr|en|ar)/?(.*)?$ !-d` is just plain wrong to begin with. You are checking if this regular expression _as the text it is_, does not match an existing directory. I assume you do not have a directory that is _literally_ named `^(fr|en|ar)/?(.*)?$` - so this condition will _always_ be true, but it absolutely does not what you appear to think it should.

Comment: yeah i don't have those directory fr/ en/ ar/ etc , if they called from the url i redirect thme to lang?=* in the background but the url will keep that fake subfolder there like `localhost/bb/fr/index.php` ... etc , so should i remove the RewriteCond since its not doing anything useful there ? and what should i do to force a default lang `localhost/bb/en/` if no lang is selected ?

Comment: So the `$1` part you are redirecting to internally, that will always match something that physically exists? Because if it doesn’t (and you had additional rewriting, to eventually translate this into some routing parameter as well), then you will have trouble figuring out when the language prefix is missing. If it always exists, then discard your current RewriteCond (which only affects the immediately following Rule btw., so this would not have affected your 2nd and 3rd rule to begin with.) […]

Comment: […] Then add a condition after the three existing rules, that checks if the requested URI does not match anything that physically exists (research it, if you don’t know how), and a Rule that will in that case redirect to the `en/` prefixed path.

Comment: @CBroe, yeah the `$1` will keep always the requests that physically exists in the url such as `localhost/bb/en/?article=1&comment=1`

Comment: @CBroe, could you help me with a code example ?

Comment: I am not giving you a verbal explanation of what you should try, just to feed you the exact code right after. Make an attempt, show what you tried, and give a proper problem description if it didn’t work.

Comment: i just tried as i explain in the main Q , and it gives an infinite loop or `localhost redirected you too many times` error , the thing is i don't have enough knowledge in .htaccess its seems to be different from the regular regex , and cant find tutorials that talk about what im doing exactly
and i read your explanation but since English is not my native lang , and my english is based on simple words cant get the complicated or the academic one , its hard for me to understand what you mean exactly and what should i do, but using code examples i can understand and learn better

Comment: Cross-site question on Webmasters SE, with accepted answer: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128204/redirect-to-default-language-directory-if-no-language-have-been-selected-htac